# Update Database - Deleting existing data and adding new data with entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have StudentRegistration Model Class as follows

```
public partial class StudentRegistration
{
    public StudentRegistration()
    {            
        this.StudentReceipts = new HashSet<StudentReceipt>();            
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StudentWalkInnID { get; set; } 
    ...
    ...  

    public virtual ICollection<StudentReceipt> StudentReceipts { get; set; }

}
public partial class StudentReceipt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StudentRegistrationID { get; set; }
    ...
    ...    

    public virtual StudentRegistration StudentRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to delete existing studentreceipt list and add new list.The `new studentreceipt list` is adding properly in the database but the `existing studentreceipt list` is not getting deleted from the database and the `StudentRegistrationId` of `existing studentreceipt list` is set to `null`.

I want to delete the existing `studentreceipt list` from the database and add new list.How can I do it ?

This is what I have tried

```
using (TransactionScope _ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  _dbRegn = _db.StudentRegistrations
    .Where(r => r.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
  if (_dbRegn != null)
  {                      
    //Remove existing receipts
    foreach (var _existingReceipt in _dbRegn.StudentReceipts.ToList())
    {
      _dbRegn.StudentReceipts.Remove(_existingReceipt);
    }                           

    //adding new receipt
    foreach (var _receipt in mdlCourseInterchange.StudentReceiptList)
    {
      StudentReceipt _studReceipt = new StudentReceipt();
      //...
      //...
      _dbRegn.StudentReceipts.Add(_studReceipt);
    }
    //...
    //..

    db.Entry(_dbRegn).State = EntityState.Modified;
    int j = _db.SaveChanges();
    if (j > 0)
    {
      _ts.Complete();
      return Json(new { message = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I have mentioned above the new studentreceipt list is adding properly in the database but the existing studentreceipt list is not getting deleted from the database .Infact the StudentRegistrationId of existing studentreceipt list is set to null.

Comment: So are there any `StudentReceipts` in `_dbRegn.StudentReceipts.ToList()`?

Comment: Yes there will be `StudentReceipts` in `_dbRegn.StudentReceipts.ToList()`.And I want to delete the existing list and add the new list

Comment: As @MarkC. suggest, if lazy loading is disabled (I suppose that), when you execute this `_dbRegn = _db.StudentRegistrations.Where(r => r.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();` you are not including the `StudentReceipts` list property. So you are removing nothing.

Comment: @JoseAlonsoMonge As you can see I am using `virtual keyword` for `Student Receipt Collection`.So I think `include` is not required here

Comment: Is lazy loading enabled in your DbContext?

Comment: @JoseAlonsoMonge Yes exactly and I hope you finally got my question :)

Comment: What is your EF version ? EF 6 or else ?

Comment: @Sampath I am using EF5.

Comment: You are not showing all the code, so I insisted on knowing if you have this: `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` or this `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; // Default` in your `DbContext` constructor

Comment: @ksg "Yes there will be `StudentReceipts`" are you optimistically saying there will be, or have you actually validated it? Your question should not be this difficult to figure out.

Comment: @JoseAlonsoMonge Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; // Default

Comment: @MarkC. The system is such that you can take registration only when receipts are added and validation is performed to ensure that.The above process is done while editing a registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
using (TransactionScope _ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  _dbRegn = _db.StudentRegistrations.Where(r => r.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

  if (_dbRegn != null)
  {                      
    //Remove existing receipts
    foreach (var _existingReceipt in _dbRegn.StudentReceipts.ToList())
    {
      __db.StudentReceipts.Remove(_existingReceipt);
    }                           

    //adding new receipt
    foreach (var _receipt in mdlCourseInterchange.StudentReceiptList)
    {
      StudentReceipt _studReceipt = new StudentReceipt();
      //...
      //...
      _db.StudentReceipts.Add(_studReceipt);
    }
    //...
    //..

    int j = _db.SaveChanges();
    if (j > 0)
    {
      _ts.Complete();
      return Json(new { message = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response mate.I have a small doubt , if accidentally something went wrong after `removal of studentreceipt and before addinng new receipt`,will the `existing receipt` will get deleted or it will get deleted only after `_ts.Complete()`

Comment: It will happen after `_ts.Complete()`.If any one of the operation fails then all operations will be rolled back.that is the key advantage of using transactions.